# which set is including $k$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, elementary-set-theory

$A=\{x^2+k \mid x \in \mathbb Z,-3 \leq x<k\}$, where $k$ is a constant.

If $\{6,9\}\subseteq A$, then which set below includes $k$?

> 1. $\{5x+1\mid x \in \mathbb Z\}$
> 2. $\{4x+3\mid x \in \mathbb Z\}$
> 3. $\{2x+6\mid x \in \mathbb Z\}$
> 4. $\{3x-4\mid x \in \mathbb Z\}$

Comment: what is $z$? maybe you wanted to write $\mathbb Z$?

Comment: yes.I don't know it's mathJax

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You know that $6=x^2+k$ and $9=y^2+k$, for some integers $x$ and $y$ with $-3\le x<k$ and $-3\le y<k$. In particular $y^2-x^2=3$. There are only a few cases for this:

1. $y+x=1$, $y-x=3$
2. $y+x=-1$, $y-x=-3$
3. $y+x=3$, $y-x=1$
4. $y+x=-3$, $y-x=-1$

Can you go on?

Comment: Now we have 4 caes for $x$ and $y$ now what to do?

Comment: @TahaAkbari For instance, case 3 gives $x=2$ and $y=1$, but then the equations with $k$ are inconsistent: $6=4+k$ and $9=1+k$. Try the other ones.

Comment: yes you are right.

Comment: I think you should swap $x$ and $y$, as $y^2 - x^2 = (y+x)(y-x)$. Nice idea, though ;)

Comment: I knew that part I just wanted to know what tio do then.

Comment: @TahaAkbari Once you have determined $k$, you can test its remainder with the division by $2$, $3$, $4$ and $5$, seeing which one matches a set in the list.

Comment: Um, *all* four are consistent.  They all give $y = \pm 2$ and $x = \pm 1$ so $k = 5$.

Answer (score 0):

Think of the gaps between squares; how many pairs of squares can you think of with a difference of 3? There should be only 1: 1 and 4. To make sure that 6 and 9 are in $A$, k must be 5. This makes it an element of 4. but not any of the other possible answers.

Comment: how about $2$ and $-1$

Comment: I was referring to the squares of the integers as opposed to the integers themselves. When that is considered, 2 and -1 still yield 4 and 1, respectively.

Comment: yes you are right.